# Formula help for multiple conditions in excel conditional fomatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a full case of Excel brain freeze trying to conditionally format cells.

Cell A1 is a number – positive or negative
A2 is the cell I want to conditionally format. Cells that don’t meet any of the following conditions remain white.

```
If A1 is positive and A2> (1.2 * A1)  formats Green
If A1 is positive and A2< (0.85 * A1)  formats Red
If A1 is negative and A2>(.85 *A1) formats Green
If A1 is negative and A2<(1.25 *A1) formats red
```

Answer (score 3):

Green:

```
=A2>A1*IF(A1>=0,1.2,0.85)
```

Red:

```
=A2<A1*IF(A1>=0,0.85,1.25)
```